# A determinant expression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Supposing $a\neq b \in \mathbb{R}$, for $$
A_n =\begin{bmatrix}
p_1 &a &\ldots &a &a \\
b &p_2 &\ldots &a &a \\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots &\vdots \\
b &b &\ldots &p_{n-1} &a\\
b &b &\ldots &b &p_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$ (Other than on the diagonal line, entries are either $a$ or $b$'s.) Show that $$
\textrm{det}(A_n) =\frac{bf(a) -af(b)}{b-a}
$$ where $$
f(x) :=(p_1-x) (p_2-x)\dotsb (p_n-x)
$$

I tried many values, and it seems to be correct. My obvious idea is to show this by mathematical induction, but things gets messy. And the expression seems to allow an application of MVT, but it is not clear how to proceed.